# Don't include merge conflict commit into git push

Tags: git

When I resolve a conflict, I have a merge commit in addition to the "real commit" I've made.
It looks as following:

```
Merge branch 'master' of http://myDomain.com/git/SIMULATOR
```

What is the best way to squash it into my "real commit", so that I have only one commit when pushing it to the server?

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch origin
git rebase master origin/master
git push origin master
```

PS. Read `man git-rebase`

Answer (score 1):

If have an existing merge commit, you can use `git rebase`, as answered by defuz—but then you will have to resolve the conflicts again.

Otherwise, use `git merge --squash` to squash changes introduced by the merge into a single commit. Resolve the conflicts if any, and run `git commit`.